# How to pass an image to 3rd party app through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a portable printer made by LG. It's name is Pocket Photo.

In my smartphone, I installed Pocket Photo. This is for adding effects to photos and print photos.

I found that its application's package name is this:

- com.lge.media.lgpocketphoto

What I want to do is to pass an image to the application.

Here is my code to send a photo to the application.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.lge.media.lgpocketphoto");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.bluecowcreative.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/hi.jpg"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Could you please give a piece of advice or code to pass data?

From Android Newbie

*** Update ***

I know how to pass and receive data between activities. The problem is that I don't know how Pocket Photo receives data. For example, I don't know what kind of a key they use.

*** Solved ***

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.lge.media.lgpocketphoto");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("http://www.bluecowcreative.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/hi.jpg"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

P.S. I appreciate for everyon who got involved in this stupid question. You saved me.

Comment: check out _intent-filter_

Comment: Intents are fired within the android system. Applications that listen to a specific intent-filter receive a message that an intent is fired with the specific filter they are listening to. I think you should know to what intent-filter the other application listens. As an example, if you install a contact application, you will be given the option to start contacts with the default android application or the installed one. This is because both applications listen to the same intent-filter.

Comment: @MaulikSheth Could you please give me more information? I've not modified the file.

Comment: Contact LG and ask them. You are attempting to hack into their activity; only they know if they support this and by what means they would accept images.

Comment: @Bram Thanks for your explanation. I can run another application from my application, but the problem is that it cannot pass an image.

Comment: @CommonsWare Are there any common rules that Android platform uses when they pass images to other applications? For example, the default Gallery app successfully pass images to LG's application (Pocket Photo).

Comment: They may support `ACTION_SEND`, but you would need to get rid of `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`.

Comment: As far as I can read on the app market does the pocket photo app receive images from the printer. This means that there is a communication between the printer and the app not between other applications and the app. This is a whole different functionality, so I would be suprised if they do offer it.

Comment: @Bram Thank you for your time. BTW, However, As I said, the default gallery app can pass images to Pocket Photo. There must be a standard way to pass data between apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why do I have to remove getLaunchIntentForPackage()?

Comment: @SungamYang: If you read the documentation for `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`, you will realize that it is not directly related to `ACTION_SEND`. Or `ACTION_VIEW`, for that matter. It is for finding the "front door" activity to the app, if there is one. You cannot just randomly slap stuff together in an `Intent` and expect it to work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your explanation. I need to learn in a normal way. I'm strugling with developing an app without fundamental knowledge.

Comment: Your "solution" is unreliable and may fail on future updates to the LG app. You are assuming that the launch activity for `com.lge.media.lgpocketphoto` also supports `ACTION_VIEW` and uses `EXTRA_STREAM`. This probably represents bugs (or at least shortcuts) in the LG app, and if they fix those, your app will break.

Comment: @CommonsWare For the time being I have no choice because of time limitation. I'll just show my app works and fix it later. Thanks for letting me the solution is fragile.